# Executing an async function in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a function, that loops through port numbers until it finds an open one:

```
async function findPort (port, app, logger) {

    const lookupPort = () => {
        return portOpen = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            app.listen(port, () => {
                logger.log("info", `Server listening on port: ${port}`);
                resolve(true);
            })
            .on('error', (err) => { 
                logger.log("warn", "port closed: " + err.port);
                reject(false);
            });
        });
    }

    let portOpen = false;

    while (portOpen === false){
        portOpen = await lookupPort();
        port++;
    }
```

When executed, it iterates through one port and then trows an exception:

> (node:2869) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: How do you execute it? Did you add an error handler?

Comment: Your question is? You haven't wrapped the the await in a try/catch and your Promise is calling reject. Also there's no point using `await lookupPart` it's not going to wait for anything in a while loop if that's what you were intending?

Comment: Because you don't have catch method that is why it's throwing an error

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have worded my question better. I was wondering why it worked only for one loop iteration? 
If understand correctly,  `await` does not stop function execution? I'm confused, because I thought that was exactly what it was supposed to do. Is it only the case of while loop or all loops? Are there any other situations where this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code above:

1) `while` loop stops its execution because `lookupPort` function throws an error (promise is rejected on `reject(false);` line) which is not caught (`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.`). To fix this try to wrap the code inside `while` loop into `try/catch` construction:

```
while (portOpen === false){
  try {
    portOpen = await lookupPort();
  }
  catch (error) {
    // handle an error here
  }
  port++;
}
```

Or if you do not want to handle the promise you reject inside `lookupPort` just remove `reject(false);` line.

2) `lookupPort` function assigns a `new Promise()` to `portOpen` variable. So even if error will be handled by `try/catch`, `portOpen === false` condition will evaluate to `false` because `portOpen` will be equal to a `Promise` object. If there is no reason to assin `portOpen` the value of the `new Promise` you should remove it.